# Pass variables to jade template from commandline

Tags: pug

I'm planning to use jade templates to generate different htmls depending on if it is in development or in production. At this time, I'm not planning to write code in node. Given this, is it possible to invoke jade from commandline and pass variables? If so, how?

if, index.jade is

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title my jade template
  body
    h1 Hello #{name}
```

I want to invoke it from command line passing value for name.

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the option `-O`/`--obj` within the Jade CLI. It accepts 2 type of values:

- Serialized JSON
- A path to a JSON file (this takes precedence)

For example:

```
jade -O myfile.json template.jade
```

or

```
jade --obj '{ "cache": true }' template.jade
```

Comment: the docs state that --obj/-O are for passing an options object.  there's not a ref to locals in the options object. what am i missing

Comment: Wow that works, but it doesn't work when I try to compile many templates.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a glitch because the json file I was using started at the array level and didn't come with a name, and because you're not 'require-ing' it, it doesn't have a name in the pug file, so I put a top level variable, and put my array inside that. For anyone else who ends up in this boat.

Comment: @cdaringe I had the same question as you. Turns out all the `render*` functions have this to say about the `options` param: "An options object, also used as the locals object"