# how to access an array of objects in jade, passed through the jade command line

Tags: pug

I can pass an array of object through the jade command line

> jade.js -P  --obj "[{\"field1\":2,\"field2\":\"valstring/obj2\"},{\"field1\":3,\"field2\":\"valstri
>   3\"}]" inventaire-all.jade

How can I access the two object into the jade template file ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variables to jade template from commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056617/pass-variables-to-jade-template-from-commandline)

Answer (score 0):

If it is object, use file (say input.json) with the object in JSON format and give filename as input.